# How do I upload .pdf files to the phone?

Tags: file-transfer

I want to read a .pdf book on my phone - and can dwnload it from dropbox. However this takes time and I want to do this with Zune of some other tool. Is there a way to do this?

**How do I upload .pdf files to the phone?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several methods:

1. You can upload to OneDrive first then download with the app.
2. You can access a link pointing to the pdf.
3. You can E-mail yourself with the PDF.

As soon as you open it will be available in Office Hub. I think you need install Adobe Reader before.

Comment: You need to install Adobe and once you have opened a file in Adobe, then it will remain in the list of opened files for a long time! (forever i think! But I can't say for sure! I have never seen that  a file I opened even in the remote past not being available on Adobe. But of course you need to kep the app installed. It won't work if you reset your phone or uninstall and reinstall the app!)

Comment: +1 for the information about the Office Hub. I use the MS PDF Reader and it doesn't seem to just pick up documents uploaded from the PC to the Documents folder but as soon as I open the Office Hub and select a document from there, PDF Reader picks it nicely. As simple as that.

Comment: You can also visit OneDrive with Internet Explorer and download files.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I've found to get a PDF on the phone itself:

1. Put it on your OneDrive. Then, open the PDF from the OneDrive app.
   It should then show up in the "My Library" of the PDF Reader app (or
   at least it does for me).
2. Connect the phone to your computer. Drag and drop the PDF to the
   Documents folder on your phone. Then, go to the Office app and it
   should be listed in your Documents. Clicking on it will open it in
   the PDF Reader app. This also seems to put it in the "My Library" of
   the PDF Reader app.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone devices do not expose their file system to applications, so whilst it is [possible to upload files to your phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/340/106), Adobe Reader would not be able to see them. I believe that the best option would be to use Onedrive; or, if you received the PDFs via email, it's worth noting that Adobe Reader will hold on to the files "for a while" so you can get to them via the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a email to yourself with the pdf file in attachment;
Using [Dropbox App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/dropbox/9wzdncrfj0pk), [Onedrive App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3), Google Docs App.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to store arbitrary files on your phone, the approach I usually take is uploading it to OneDrive and then downloading it from the OneDrive app. This will keep the file cached on the phone if I remember correctly, also check the office section after you downloaded if it appears there.

If you have problems with it taking too much time; you should look into PDF compression techniques, or techniques that reduce the size by taking away unnecessary images / backgrounds. I have had no problems viewing PDF / PowerPoint / ... files on my phone, so it should be easy to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to install the free app PDF Reader from Microsoft Corporation. Then take a Gmail-account and send yourself an email with the PDF-file as attachment. So far no news. As soon as you receive the mail on your Windows Phone you tab the attachment and it opens in the newly installed PDF-reader. But here it comes: in Gmail settings you create a label under Postbox In called PDF's. There you store all your emails with PDF-attachments. Raedy you are !

Answer (score -1):

You can use this app called PDF reader. http://www.appx4fun.com/xap/1104/. You can later convert the PDF file to TXT, BMP, JPG, GIF, PNG, WMF, EMF, EPS, TIFF. All you have to do is on receiving the PDF download it and it will automatically get downloaded in the PDF reader app.
This app definitely helps.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That application is for PCs. How does it help with getting a PDF file to a phone?

Comment: I have changed it

Answer (score -2):

Use Quick1PDF http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=c569ae3b-d5ff-422b-8476-2f7e6a2a1f95
create pdf files, view your pdf files and send via email or upload to Onedrive