# Connecting Windows Phone 7 smartphone to the computer without Zune

Tags: zune, lumia

Is using Zune the only way to access the phone's files via the computer? I assumed that at the very least I would be able to access the Lumia 610's mass memory directly from Windows Explorer as an external disk, but it kept complaining until I downloaded and installed Zune. Personally I hardly ever use Nokia Suite for my N8, unless there's an update I need to install. I also never use the Store/Marketplace, so I didn't see the point of getting yet another programme to take up precious resources on my poor computer.

Comment: I hated Zune as well. Window Phone 8 is better and doesn't use Zune.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zune desktop software is the only method for syncing files on your Windows Phone 7, but this only syncs photos, music, videos and podcasts. If you're looking to backup data files generated by apps you're out of luck unless they provide a cloud (OneDrive, DropBox) backup option. The Office hub already backs up to your OneDrive.

Comment: Sigh. Thank you

Comment: Once the Zune drivers are installed, it **is** [possible to use the phone as a mass storage device without having to use Zune](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/316/106)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Thanks! I just installed Zune and then left it without doing anything, I'll definitely try out the hack.

Answer (score 4):

Yes!!!
On a Windows PC you can access your phone as a mass storage. 
Complete Steps below. You can refer the article linked [here](http://mynokiablog.com/2011/12/11/how-to-enable-mass-storage-on-your-lumia-800/) for detailed steps.

1. Connect your Windows phone to PC.
2. Open Registry editor.
3. Navigate to click *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB*.
4. Press *Ctrl+F* and search for ***"ZuneDriver"***. Make sure USB folder is selected before searching
5. Navigate to the *VID_045E&PID_04EC&MI_00* folder under which ZuneDriver is located.
6. Click on the device parameters.

   - ShowInShell and change its value from 0 to 1 .
   - PortableDeviceNameSpaceExcludeFromShell and change its value from 1 to 0 .
   - EnableLegacySupport from 0 to 1 .
7. Remove the Lumia and insert it again.

Comment: It's 2019, and this trick worked to get photos off my old Lumia 710. Thanks for this. I'm still looking for a way to get some other (non-photo) files from the phone.

Comment: Still works in 2021 with Windows 10 and my LG Optimus 7 running WP7.8. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

if you have unlocked mobile than you have many other ways..

Comment: Could you please provide some examples?

Answer (score -2):

You need to connect the first phone to the computer using its USB cable. Launch Nokia PC Suite on the computer, go to the "Synchronize." When the Nokia PC window opens, click "Settings," "Create New Settings." Complete the prompts to transfer your data.
Plug your second phone and run the PC suite and import the file into your phone

Comment: The Nokia Suite is not for Windows Phone devices.