# How to get a filesystem on my phone?

Tags: 7.8

Is there a way to get a file system on my Lumia 800 with Windows Phone 7.8? I dislike using Zune and would like to see and copy directly from my file manager. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Another similar one which has solution via editing the registry (not sure if it still works in Win 7.8) http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/316/295

Answer (score 2):

No unless you root the device.

In fact, it is impossible to have access to windows phone (either **7.x or 8.0**) file-system for 3rd party applications (because they are sand-boxed and bounded to an isolated storage) and Microsoft has not provided such utility up to now (as far as I know).

Therefore there is no such utility application either on phone or even on PC. Zune sounds to be the only solution for syncing some sort of files (**Music, Pictures…**)

If you root the device then you may have access to file-system as there was on older versions of Windows Mobile and Windows CE.

Comment: And are there "secure" not official wP systems that support this. I mean secure, that it doesn't brick my phone etc.. I saw a not official 7.8 with which I can download apps for free, and I know its illegal but with these, can I have a file system? If yes, can you post example OSs? Thanks :)

Comment: sorry I've updated the answer. The only way to have access to file-system is rooting the device meaning you have to replace original ROM image with modified ROM. There is no guarantee in that and it not only break warranty but also may harm your device.